# How to implement ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA-2 communication in OpenSSL?

Tags: tls, cryptography, openssl, c, c++

**Full question**

How do you implement client and server based solution-pair to secure network communication for simple C++-based desktop (non-browser) programs utilising the ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA-2 cipher-suite using OpenSSL?

**Pre-text**

I am a novice into using any cryptography other than pushing things into hashes and bcrypt. I need to secure flowing network data from clients to a server so a general purpose client-server solution is required. The mentioned cipher suite seems to be the big fat thing currently, providing many mitigations and benefits.

**Resources**

1. https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/
2. https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Main_Page

**Problem**

I appreciate the work done by the OpenSSL devs to maintain documentation. But I can't find anything that does not require you to be a security professional to implement the said cipher suite in a client-server architecture. There seems to be no examples on the internet or the mentioned resources.

Do I really need to spend months or years to figure all this stuff out?

So far I'm guessing I need to figure out AES in GCM mode separately **then** ECDHE key generation **then** RSA key generation and **then** somehow stitch it all together **myself**?

Comment: I'm no expert either, but of I've learnt one thing from the crypto disasters of the last years: if you're not an expert, you have absolutely no business in implementing crypto for production usage. Go ahead and play, learn, explore openSSL, but don't try and upstream you're results unless you've gotten enough experience in the process that you're confident that no hard-to-spot bugs have made it into your code base.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm afraid that is not sounds advise. I'm sure there are lots of peple out there like me who need security but lack the resources to hire professionals.

Comment: let's find a comparison: there's a lot of people who'd need heart surgery but can't afford a proper surgeon. If you're not a surgeon, leave the patient closed. The moment you operate the patient, you actually decrease the patient's life expectation, though you definitely meant to do the opposite

Comment: By the way, remove the unrelated tags. You don't mention c++ or TLS in your question, and even C is only vaguely related, and IMHO shouldn't be used

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not asking if I should implement it or not. I need to. It's simple as that really. And by saying "if you are no expert don't do it" doens't really contribute other than potentially leaving the customer base unprotected at all!

Comment: You are planning to link against openssl, right?  OpenSSL has a function for every part of that communication suite (the string in your title).  But the question really is, what is your thread model?  You do not need any cryptography to talk on the loopback interface, but you need more than just a cryptographic suite to talk securely over the internet.

Comment: @grochmal my understanding was that op wanted to implement that cipher himself, hence my confusion! I do hope he's really just going to use openSSL, not extend it!

Comment: I know :) , that's against rule 1 of cryptography: *don't roll your own*.  Btw, Infogeek, if you *need* to implement something simply because you need to do it, instead of evaluating its implications, then your question has nothing to do with information security.  Information security is the process of evaluating the risk, not the process of coding it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, no. I want to use OpenSSL to achieve a communictaion secured by those ciphers, not to roll my equivalent of them. The question is about programatic how-to. Was this the wrong place to ask?

Comment: Infogeek, if this question is really just "how do I program library xyz to do ABC", then, indeed, this is the wrong forum. Try stackoverflow, and make sure to share your attempts!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to link libssl from openssl into your server and your client executables to have a TLS server and TLS client with hardcoded TLS version (1.2) and hardcoded cipher suite (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) and I guess a hardcoded pinned certificate?

I suggest you use something like libcurl in your client, which is higher level than libssl. It uses libssl but does most of the work for you.

I suggest you look at the code of nginx to see how to do a TLS server using openssl. It has some code you don't need because it handles more features than you need, but it's a start. Also you should decide to only use openssl 1.0.2, which removes a bunch of code to support older versions.

If you produce libssl and libcrypto object code to link into your executables, you can and should avoid bundling a lot of the code that is compiled by default but not used by your application. So don't compile md5 and sha1 (you'll only use sha256 certificates). Don't compile any ciphers other than AES. Don't compile any elliptic curves other than P-256 (or 25519).

Alternatively, you can bundle shared libraries produced with default compilation flags, but that means a lot more code that might run.

Comment: I was thinking that since it's all isolated to the cipher suite I mentioned then TLS support is not needed? A good note on compiling only the necessary ciphers, something I will keep in mind.

Comment: @Infogeek You need all the parts. You want forward secrecy, you use ephemeral key exchange provided by ECDHE. You need authenticated encryption, so you use AES-GCM. You need a KDF to generate symmetric keys so you use SHA2. If you expose the client executable, you can't use pre-shared keys, so you need public key authentication provided by RSA/ECDSA/EdDSA. So you need all the machinery provided by TLS, except you limit most of the options in negotiation. If you don't need to use TLS but just want secure communication then use libsodium - it's more secure and much easier to use.

Comment: @Infogeek there is no such thing as "just use the cipher suite". You need a secure implementation of a secure protocol. You must not roll your own protocol because you will 100% make it insecure. So you can use TLS or you can use libsodium. Those are the recommendations by the crypto and security community. libsodium is much preferred if you don't need the compatibility of TLS. TLS with harcoded self-signed certificate and only 1 version and 1 good cipher suite avoid most of the pitfalls of TLS, though it is much more code (thus more possible bugs) than libsodium.

Comment: TLS is a protocol to negotiate ciphers for further communication nad use those ciphers, correct? If I want just the cipher suite mentioned doesn't that mean it stops being TLS? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @Infogeek Your TLS client sends ClientHello with cipher suite list of length 1, and it checks the certificate by comparing its hash value with a hardcoded value, and it verifies the digital signature to make sure there is no MiTM, and it generates its ephemeral key, and it uses the two ephemeral keys to generate symmetric keys, and then it exchanges encrypted and authenticated records with the server. Exactly like a browser's TLS client, except it doesn't care whether the domain name from the URL is in the certificate.

Comment: @Infogeek your TLS server always chooses TLS 1.2, the 1 cipher suite it supports & P-256 curve, always closes connection on anything incompatible, always shows the same certificate, always signs the new ephemeral key using the key from the certificate, then exchanges encrypted and authenticated records with the client. Exactly like IIS/Apache/Nginx configured to support only TLS 1.2 with 1 cipher suite and one curve with a single certificate regardless of the domain in SNI. Very much regular TLS. You can skip the certificate code and 1 network round trip delay by using libsodium.

Comment: Thanks a lot. seems i do have to study each part to deploy the overall scheme afterall.